# Why are $_POST nor $_GET working in this forms?

Tags: php, html, post, mysqli, get

I'm practicing PHP and MySQLi y creating a class assistance system (Checking for students' assistance to a classroom). However, I seem to be stuck with a problem...

What I want to do is simple: Teachers enter a four-digit code they possess (saved in a database) to login. Their code is posted to the page `uad_asist_class.php` and this page will perform a query in the database, showing the teacher's name for a simple greeting (all info in database).

EXAMPLE: Teacher enters code: 5690, page shows "Buenos dias, Pedro Romo"

The problem is neither `$_GET` nor `$_POST` are sending the code to the page (I checked the POST array and it's empty). I want to know what am I doing wrong. (Feel free to rip my code a new one, it's for a practice).

Here's the code:

index.php: This guy sends the code the teacher enters

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <!--
        Load the page to adapt to the viewport on any devices
    -->
    <meta 
        name = "viewport" 
        content = "width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">

        <head>
            <!--
                Load script file
                Loads the functions for this page
            -->
            <script 
                type = "text/javascript" 
                src = "../js/UAD-password-login.js?v=1.8">
            </script>

            <!--
                Load the stylesheet
                This stylesheet contains:
                >> Buttons styling
                >> Paragraphs and text styling
                >> Custom formularies
            -->
            <link
                rel = "stylesheet"
                type = "text/css"
                href = "../css/UAD-main-style.css?v=2.3">

            <!--
                Page title on Chrome, Firefox tabs
            -->
            <title>
                Inicio de sesión
            </title>
        </head>

         <!--
            The page performs the function RealTimeClock
            This function is defined on file "UAD-realtime-clock.js"            
         -->
        <body onload = "RealTimeClock()">
            <!--
                Page main heading 
            -->
            <center>

                <!--
                    This heading shows the title of the page
                    This heading uses the style "uad_heading_01"
                -->
                <h1
                    id = "uad_heading_01"
                    align = "center"
                    style = "font-size:56px">
                    Inicio de sesión
                </h1>
            </center>

            <center>

                <!--
                    A subtitle, indicating the user what to do
                -->
                <p
                    class = "uad_text"
                    align = "center"
                    style = "font-size:24px">       
                    Introduzca su clave de profesor para iniciar sesión...
                </p>
            </center>

            <br>

            <!--
                Formulary inputs
            -->
            <form 
                action = "/uad_asist_class.php" 
                method = "post">
                <!--
                    This class denotes a row, grouping divs in a horizontal line
                -->
                <div
                    class = "row">

                    <!--
                        This class denotes a column
                        A group of elements vertically aligned 
                    -->
                    <div
                        class = "col"
                        align = "center">

                        <!--
                            Password bar
                            Password is captured here by the number buttons
                        -->
                        <input
                            id = "prof_password"
                            name = "clave"
                            class = "uad_password_input"
                            type = "text"
                            required
                            disabled = "disabled"
                            placeholder = "Clave..."
                            maxlength = "4">

                        <br><br>

                        <!--
                            Log In button
                            After inserting a password, log in with the teacher username
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_form_button"
                            type = "submit"
                            value = "I N I C I A R">

                        <!--
                            Eye button
                            Serves to show or hide the password
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_eyeicon_button"
                            onclick = "HideShowPassword()"
                            type = "button">

                    </div>

                    <br><br>

                    <!--
                        This class denotes a column
                        A group of elements vertically aligned 
                    -->
                    <div
                        class = "col"
                        align = "center">

                        <!--
                            Number 1 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('1')"
                            value = "1">            

                        <!--
                            Number 2 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('2')"
                            value = "2">

                        <!--
                            Number 3 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('3')"
                            value = "3">

                        <br>


                        <!--
                            Number 4 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('4')"
                            value = "4">            

                        <!--
                            Number 5 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('5')"
                            value = "5">

                        <!--
                            Number 6 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('6')"
                            value = "6">

                        <br>


                        <!--
                            Number 7 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('7')"
                            value = "7">            

                        <!--
                            Number 8 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('8')"
                            value = "8">

                        <!--
                            Number 9 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('9')"
                            value = "9">

                        <br>


                        <!--
                            Backspace button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_del_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "ErasePassword()"
                            value = "<">
                        <!-- &#8592; -->

                        <!--
                            Number 0 button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_num_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "InsertPassword('0')"
                            value = "0">

                        <!--
                            Clear password input button
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_clear_button"
                            type = "button"
                            onclick = "ClearPassword()"
                            value = "C">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <br>

            <!--
                Real-time clock
                Shows a real time clock on screen
            -->
            <div
                class = "uad_text"
                id = "realTimeClock"
                align = "center"
                style = "font-size:76px">
            </div>

            <br>

            <!--
                Real-time Date
                Shows today's date in a format
            -->
            <div
                class = "uad_text"
                id = "todayDate"
                align = "center"
                style = "font-size:32px">
            </div>

            <!--
                Footer of the page
                Shows the information of the school, and the year of development
            -->
            <div
                class = "uad_footer">
                Universidad de Artes Digitales &copy 2018 - Guadalajara, Jalisco, M&eacutexico
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

uad_asist_class.php: This guy receives the code entered by the teacher, displaying info according to the input

```
    <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    uad_asist_class.html

    This is the main page to capture students assistance in class.
    Here, a teacher has logged in and starts capturing assistance by pressing buttons with the students' names. A buttons press adds a "NOT PRESENT" to that class block for the day, adding new absences after every class block.

Class blocks are intervals of 50 min for classes. There can be up to four blocks of that class per day, and only four blocks can exist weekly.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <!--
        Load the character set
    -->
    <meta
        charset = "UTF-8">

        <!--
            Page head
        -->
        <head>

            <!--
                Load the JavaScript script
                - Functions to show 
            -->
            <script
                type = "text/javascript"
                src = "../js/UAD-capture-assistance.js?v=1.7">
            </script>

            <!--
                Load this page's stylesheet
            -->
            <link
                rel = "stylesheet"
                type = "text/css"
                href = "../css/UAD-assisthub-style.css?v=3.1">

            <!--
                Load the main stylesheet
            -->
            <link
                rel = "stylesheet"
                type = "text/css"
                href = "../css/UAD-main-style.css?v=2.4">

            <!--
                Page title
                Title for the tabs
            -->
            <title>
                Toma de asistencias
            </title>
        </head>

        <!--
            Body of the page 
        -->
        <body onload = "AssistMain()">

            <div>

                <!--
                    1st row: 
                -->
                <div
                    class = "row">

                    <!--
                        1st column:
                    -->
                    <div
                        class = "col"
                        align = "center">

                        <!--
                            Display the university's logo
                            Check path "../Intranet_UAD/media/image/" for logo
                        -->
                        <img
                            src = "../media/image/uad_logo.png"
                            align = "center"
                            width = "413px"
                            height = "auto">
                    </div>

                    <!--
                        2nd column: WELCOME TO THE USER
                        Display a greeting message to the teacher.
                        Values change depending on the user who logged in
                    -->
                    <div
                        class = "col"
                        align = "center">

                        <!--
                            Display a simple greeting to the user
                        -->
                        <h1
                            id = "uad_heading_01"
                            align = "center"
                            style = "font-size:72px;">
                            ¡Buen dia!
                        </h1>

                        <!--
                            Display the user's name
                            Value changes depending on logged user
                        -->
                        <p
                            class = "uad_text"
                            align = "center"
                            style = "font-size:44px;">
                            <?php
                                if(isset($_POST["clave"]))
                                {   
                                    echo "La clave insertada es: " . $_POST["clave"];
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    echo "Error!";
                                }
                                /*
                                $prof_clave = "";

                                $servername = "localhost";
                                $username = "root";
                                $password = "";
                                $dbname = "uad_personnel";

                                // Connection to database saved here
                                $connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                                //
                                if($connection->connect_errno)
                                {
                                    //
                                    die();
                                }

                                if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
                                {
                                    $prof_clave = test_input($_POST['clave']);
                                }

                                function test_input($input)
                                {
                                    $input = trim($input);
                                    $input = stripslashes($input);
                                    $input = htmlspecialchars($input);

                                    return $input;
                                }

                                echo "La clave insertada es: " . $prof_clave;

                                $query = "SELECT nombre FROM profesores WHERE 'clave' LIKE '" . $prof_clave . "%'";

                                //
                                $result = $connection->query($query);

                                //
                                if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                                {
                                    // output data of each row
                                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                                    {
                                        //
                                        echo $row['nombre'] . "<br>";
                                    }
                                } 

                                else 
                                {
                                    //
                                    echo "nombre no disponible";
                                }

                                //
                                $connection->close();
                                */
                            ?>

                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <!--
                        3rd column: CAREER LOGO
                        Show an image of the class' career.
                        Changes depending on the career the class belongs.

                        Values are:
                        - IDV : Ingenieria en Desarrollo de Videojuegos
                        - LDDA : Lic. en Diseño y Desarrollo de Aplicaciones
                        - LA : Lic. en Animación
                        - LPA : Lic. en Producción Audiovisual

                        Check path "../Intranet/media/image/" for the career logos
                    -->
                    <div
                        class = "col"
                        align = "center">
                        <!--
                            Display the university's logo
                            Check path "../Intranet_UAD/media/image/" for logo
                        -->
                        <img
                            src = "../media/image/idv_logo.png"
                            align = "center"
                            width = "auto"
                            height = "auto">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--
                    2nd row: INFO DISPLAY
                    - Class name. Info to display to teacher, changes depending on time.
                    - Date info. Display to user and used to insert data on ABSENCE table on database
                    - Student buttons. Click to set student as NOT PRESENT.
                    - Click again to unmark as NOT PRESENT.
                -->
                <div
                    class = "row">

                    <!--
                        1st column: CAPTURE ASSISTANCES
                        - Save the assistance data on the table.
                    -->
                    <div
                        class = "col"
                        align = "center">
                        <div
                            id = "ClockDisplay"
                            class = "uad_text"
                            align = "center"
                            style = "font-size: 48px;">
                        </div>

                        <br>

                        <div
                            id = "DateDisplay"
                            class = "uad_text"
                            align = "center"
                            style = "font-size: 24px"
                        >
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--
                        2nd column: CAPTURE ASSISTANCES
                        - Save the assistance data on the table.
                    -->
                    <div
                        class = "col"
                        align = "center">
                        <div
                            class = "uad_text"
                            align = "center"
                            style = "font-size: 48px;">
                            Fundamentos de Fisica I
                        </div>  
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <br><br><br>

                <?php
                    // Here we control the buttons to get the information to present the pages
                    // Here we will...
                    /*
                        1- Load a new 
                    */
                ?>

                <!--
                    3rd row: INFO DISPLAY
                    - Class name. Info to display to teacher, changes depending on time.
                    - Date info. Display to user and used to insert data on ABSENCE table on database
                    - Student buttons. Click to set student as NOT PRESENT.
                    - Click again to unmark as NOT PRESENT.
                -->
                <div
                    class = "row">
                    <!--
                        1st column: CAPTURE ASSISTANCES
                        - Save the assistance data on the table.
                    -->
                    <div
                        class = "col"
                        align = "center">
                        <!--
                            1st column: CAPTURE ASSISTANCES
                            - Save the assistance data on the table.
                        -->
                        <input
                            class = "uad_long_button"
                            type = "button"
                            align = "center"
                            value = "Capturar">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>



            <!--
                Footer of the page
                Shows the information of the school, and the year of development
            -->
            <div
                class = "uad_footer">
                Universidad de Artes Digitales &copy 2018 - Guadalajara, Jalisco, México
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Also, i'm using XAMPP, phpmyadmin ver. 4.5.1 with default user and password information (Whatever else I need to check and wasn't added, please let me know)

Comment: I forgot...
The commented code in the second php returns this output: Notice: Undefined index: clave in "directory". The query performs ok, since the names in the table are actually shown properly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only input field that has the attribute `name` is **clave** . But this will not be sent in the `$_POST` variable if it has the `disabled="disabled"` attribute, since disabled fields will not be passed with form submission.  If you want the field to be non-editable set it as `readonly` instead and you would still be able to fetch it with in `$_POST` variable.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! I'll check my code more often for details like this... Now the post works and I just gotta work on my query to match the value with the data on my database.